# float top and inline display

Tags: html, css

i have a division with an image and a table inside of it :

```
<div>
 <img>
 <table style='display:inline-block'>
  <tr>
   <td>insert your name here:</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td><input></td>
  </tr>
 </table>
</div>
```

this is also a [**link**](http://aminet.6te.net/website.htm) for my page
the problem is that the table is floated to the bottom, why ?
how can i make them (the img and the table) both at the same line ? and not floated down and top

Comment: please specify browser and viewport width because on fx22 it works as expected

Comment: google chrome  
this how it looks like ![image](http://i37.servimg.com/u/f37/11/89/27/52/110.jpg)

Comment: I think that for tables `display: inline-table` is more suitable than `inline-block` for this purpose.

Answer (score 1):

Simple have the

```
img {float:left}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your CSS do:

```
img {
    float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should make a CSS style sheet for this, but in your  tag, add in float:left; and everything will flow up and to the left.

CSS:

```
 img {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 red;
    display: inline-block;
    float:left;
 }
```